# Bounce-modulo two numbers

Tags: code-golf, math, number, arithmetic

The graph of the modulo operation (\$y = x \mod k\$) looks like this:

[image: Graph of the modulo function]

This is a very useful function, as it allows us to create "wrapping" behavior. However, it is very cumbersome when I want to use it to create an appearance of "bouncing" between two walls. The graph of the "bounce" function (\$y = \text{bounce} (x, k)\$) looks like this:

[image: Graph of the "bounce-modulo" function]

The [period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_function) of the graph of \$y = x \mod k\$ is \$k\$. The period of the graph of \$y = \text{bounce} (x, k)\$ is \$2k\$, because it moves upwards for \$k\$ units, and then moves downwards for another \$k\$ units, before returning to where it started. For both functions, the minimum value for \$y\$ is 0, and the maximum is \$k\$ (Actually, for the modulus function with integral inputs, it's \$k-1\$). In addition, for both functions, the value where \$x=0\$ is 0.

### The challenge

Given an integer \$x\$ and a positive integer \$k\$, return an integer or floating-point approximation of \$y = \text{bounce} (x, k)\$.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest valid submission (counted in bytes) wins.

### Test Cases

```
  x,  k -> bounce(x, k)
  0, 14 ->            0
  3,  7 ->            3
 14, 14 ->           14
 15, 14 ->           13
-13, 14 ->           13 (12.999997 etc would be an acceptable answer)
-14, 14 ->           14
191,  8 ->            1
192,  8 ->            0
```

Bonus points for a [Fourier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_wave)-based approach in [Fourier](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fourier).

Comment: "*For both functions, the minimum value for x is 0, and the maximum is k*" is just plain wrong.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Whoops. I means the result.

Comment: Oops, that's what I thought it said already. It's still wrong. `k % k = 0`

Comment: @PeterTaylor Oh, I understand your question. I had originally designed this with floating-point in mind, then switched to just ints after. Will edit.

Comment: @PeterTaylor If the arguments are floats, then the maximum is a number arbitrarily close to `k`.

Comment: Shouldn't the `-11, 14` testcase yield `11`?

Comment: @notjagan Fixed.

Comment: I think I've misunderstood: shouldn't the cases resulting in `14` with `14` as `k` actually be `0`? This is what I based my answer on.

Comment: @notjagan No. The function has a period of `2k`. Zeroes only occur when `x % 2k = 0`.

Answer (score 8):

## x86-64 Machine Code, 18 bytes

```
97
99
31 D0
29 D0
99
F7 FE
29 D6
A8 01
0F 45 D6
92
C3
```

This code defines a function in x86-64 machine language that computes `bounce(x, k`). Following the [System V AMD64 calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI) used on Gnu/Unix systems, the `x` parameter is passed in the `EDI` register, while the `k` parameter is passed in the `ESI` register. As with all x86 calling conventions, the result is returned in the `EAX` register.

To call this from C, you would prototype it as follows:

```
int Bounce(int x, int k);
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY7RaoMwFIavl6cIloGROBK11mA3GN18iWUXIVobaOOI6QiMvfqyOL2dvQjh/N/5@Y5Meym9l4MeLZQnYaCrysPQdm/v8BFG3LFdeIy7nHL3QrjL2PxPWRNY87pkJXfPFXck7JGGu2I7Zyzj7pBHNRitsEpCpS2MkyBpnEZxmPAUoSBbxDUAYKO0PF/bDu5H26rh4fQEwFS8CKWnDhSml/jv3iSZhk/0Be4@TEDHOLpXXEcYzo6YYFogVP@Hc7xbobRYb9PtOk9pfmvhloFRXK3ybOGms1ejIanBt/c/8ngW/ejTS1n8Ag)**

Ungolfed assembly mnemonics:

```
; Take absolute value of input 'x' (passed in EDI register).
; (Compensates for the fact that IDIV on x86 returns a remainder with the dividend's sign,
; whereas we want 'modulo' behavior---the result should be positive.)
xchg   eax, edi      ; swap EDI and EAX (put 'x' in EAX)
cdq                  ; sign-extend EAX to EDX:EAX, effectively putting sign bit in EDX
xor    eax, edx      ; EAX ^= EDX
sub    eax, edx      ; EAX -= EDX

; Divide EDX:EAX by 'k' (passed in ESI register).
; The quotient will be in EAX, and the remainder will be in EDX.
; (We know that EAX is positive here, so we'd normally just zero EDX before division,
; but XOR is 2 bytes whereas CDQ is 1 byte, so it wins out.)
cdq
idiv   esi

; Pre-emptively subtract the remainder (EDX) from 'k' (ESI),
; leaving result in ESI. We'll either use this below, or ignore it.
sub    esi, edx

; Test the LSB of the quotient to see if it is an even number (i.e., divisible by 2).
; If not (quotient is odd), then we want to use ESI, so put it in EDX.
; Otherwise (quotient is even), leave EDX alone.
test   al, 1
cmovnz edx, esi

; Finally, swap EDX and EAX to get the return value in EAX.
xchg   eax, edx
ret
```

Note that the first section (that takes the absolute value) could have equivalently been written:

```
; Alternative implementation of absolute value
xchg    eax, edi
neg     eax
cmovl   eax, edi
```

which is the exact same number of bytes (6). The performance should be similar, perhaps slightly faster (except on [certain Intel chips, where conditional moves are slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44754267/how-to-force-the-use-of-cmov-in-gcc-and-vs/44759962#44759962)).

`XCHG` is, of course, relatively slow and would not be preferred over `MOV` except in code golfing (since the `XCHG` is 1-byte when one of the operands is the accumulator, whereas a register-register `MOV` is always 2 bytes).

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <strike>29</strike> 27 bytes

```python
lambda x,k:abs(x%k-x/k%2*k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaFCJ9sqMalYo0I1W7dCP1vVSCtb839BUWZeiUaahoGOgqGJpiYXjG@so2COxDU0QZM3NEUT0DU0xhDB0GRpqKNggSJgBBb4DwA)

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
æ%A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wMlXH/4eX6z9qWvP/f3S0gY6hSaxOtLGOOZA0NIHwDE0htK6hMYwBk7E01LEA00ZAOhYA)

Built-ins ftw.

#### Explanation

`æ%` is a useful built-in here. I don't know how to describe it, so I'll just provide the output for some inputs:

As `x` goes from `0` to infinity, `xæ%4` goes `0,1,2,3,4,(-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,)` where the part in parentheses is repeated to infinity both ways.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 27 bytes

```python
lambda x,k:k-abs(k-x%(k*2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaFCJ9sqWzcxqVgjW7dCVSNby0hT839BUWZeiUaahoGOgqGJpiYXjG@so2COxDU0QZM3NEUT0DU0xhDB0GRpqKNggSJgBBb4DwA)

Answer (score 4):

### Ruby, <strike>40 bytes</strike> 32 bytes

```
b=->(x,k){(x/k+1)%2>0?x%k:k-x%k}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P8lW106jQidbs1qjQj9b21BT1cjOwL5CNdsqWxdI1v6vULBVSE8tKdZLzsjPLdAryY/P5MrGIlZQWlKskKSXnJiTAzRPIVvzvwGXoQkA)

#### Explanation

Hi, this is my first answer on this site!  This code is based on the observation that the bounce function behaves exactly like modulo when (*n*-1)*k* <= *x* < *nk* and n is odd, and behaves like a reversed modulo operation when *n* is even.  `(x/k+1)` is the smallest integer greater than *x*/*k* (which is *x*/*k*+1 rounded down to an integer).  Therefore, `(x/k+1)` finds the *n* mentioned above.  `%2>0` checks to see if *n* is odd or even.  If *n* mod 2 > 0, then *n* is odd.  If *n* mod 2 = 0, then *n* is even.  If *n* is odd, then the bounce function should equal *x* mod *k*.  If *n* is even, the bounce function should be the reverse, equal to *k* - *x* mod *k*.  The whole expression `(x/k+1)%2>0?x%k:k-x%k` finds *n*, then executes the *x* mod *k* if it is odd, and executes *k* - *x* mod *k* otherwise.

The answer was improved based on a suggestion from [Cyoce](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41042/cyoce).

Comment: You can convert this to a lambda. Instead of `def b(x,k) ... end` use `->x,k{...}`

Comment: And since you're dealing with integers, `.to_i` isn't necessary.

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>36</s> 32 bytes

```
k=>f=x=>x<0?f(-x):x>k?k-f(k-x):x
```

Recursively bounces `x` against `0` and `k`, so very much in the spirit of the challenge.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 19 bytes

```
Abs@Mod[#,2#2,-#2]&
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 5 bytes

```
aa%Ey
```

[Verify all testcases.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=aa%25Ey&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=14%0A0%0A%0A7%0A3%0A%0A14%0A14%0A%0A14%0A15%0A%0A14%0A-13%0A%0A14%0A-14%0A%0A8%0A191%0A%0A8%0A192%0A&debug=0&input_size=3)

Fork of [my Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/132665/48934).

Answer (score 1):

## J, 25 bytes

Hint:

> This is just regular modulo on the ladder numbers.  For example, in the case of 5: `0 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1`

Here is a (not yet well-golfed) solution in J.  Will try to improve tomorrow:

```
[ ((|~ #) { ]) (i.@>:,}:@i.@-) @ ]
```

compressed: `[((|~#){])(i.@>:,}:@i.@-)@]`

compressed2: `[((|~#){])(<:|.|@}.@i:)@]`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/oPBEkKtnoK0QoaGjV1CsqaCtUKsZoKGpl6DnZWOrVWDkCGrqaCg0Isl7lCkoIxl6GlIZC24Io3NAbShiYA)

Comment: I feel like `i:` can be used here, but I haven't tried a solution yet

Comment: @ConorO'Brien check out my compressed2 version, it saves a few bytes using `i:`.  Just haven't had time to update the main one and provide an explanation.  I expect an expert could shave off another 4 or 5 bytes at least...

Comment: `((|~#){])]-|@}:@i:` for 18 bytes

Comment: @miles beautiful, tyvm

Answer (score 1):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), <s>25</s> <s>30</s> 27 bytes

```
g=abs(:%:)~a'\`b%2|?b-g\?g
```

Did a bit of restructuring...

### Explanation

```
g=abs(   )  let g be the absolute value of 
       %    the (regular) modulo between
      : :   input a read from cmd line, and input b read from cmd line
~a \ b%2    IF the int division of A and B mod 2 (ie parity test) yields ODD
  ' `         (int divisions need to be passed to QBasic as code literals, or ELSE...)
|?b-g       THEN print bouncy mod
\?g         ELSE print regular mod
```

Comment: Does QBIC do something different for MOD operations than other Basic implementations do? Other Basics return MOD with the same sign as the dividend; that would fail when `x` is -13 and `k` is 14.

Comment: @CodyGray Nope, it gave -13. Fixed now.

Comment: Don't you need `abs` both times?

Comment: @Neil do you have a testcase for that?

Comment: @Neil nvm, I've fixed it by restructuring the whole thing.

Comment: You only need `abs` once, because `k` is guaranteed to be positive. Or, I guess if it's shorter, you can indeed just do the absolute value of the modulo operation, as in your revised version.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>40</s> 50 bytes

damn dollars. damn import overhead. :)

integer version:

```php
[,$x,$k]=$argv;$y=abs($x)%$k;echo$x/$k&1?$k-$y:$y;
```

or

```php
[,$x,$k]=$argv;echo[$y=abs($x)%$k,$k-$y][$x/$k&1];
```

float version, 56 bytes:

Replace `abs($x)%$k` with `fmod(abs($x),$k)`.

---

edit: fixed results for negative `x`

Comment: "Damn dollars". Yeah, money stinks...

Comment: How about `€argv` or `£argv`? Those would look nice :x

Answer (score 1):

## C89, 40 bytes

```
t;f(x,k){t=abs(x%k);return x/k%2?k-t:t;}
```

A C port of [my x86 machine code answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/132670/58518), this defines a function, `f`, that calculates the bounce-modulo for the parameters `x` and `k`.

It uses C89's implicit-int rule, so that both parameters, the global variable `t`, and the function's return value are all implicitly of type `int`. The global variable `t` is just used to hold a temporary value, which ends up saving bytes, compared to repeating the computation on either side of the conditional operator.

The `abs` function (absolute value) is provided in the `<stdlib.h>` header, but we don't have to include it here, again thanks to C89's implicit-int rule (where the function is implicitly declared and assumed to return `int`).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fdDRCoIwGAXg63yKYQibzFIz0Jb1It2s6XToVkwNQXz1loKX6d1/@ODA@ZlXMGaMJBz2uEKDTOmzgb1TIaLzttMK9MfKCe@VJy@SjGYvFKu7LAfXps3E61DeLEuoFkgqFJwPqguGASupdt05fNBg7d56Ig5tRzyUjQGHPg4ihMgfCaJ1Oq@SF5w2bKMyCXC8RuFCyyN8Yo3my3hNi8Z40/yUxckP)**

**Ungolfed version:**

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int Bounce(int x, int k)
{
    int mod = abs(x % k);
    return (x/k % 2) ? k-mod : mod;
}
```

Looking at this in light of [my hand-tuned machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/132670/58518), compilers actually [generate pretty good output](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,source:%27%23include+%3Cstdlib.h%3E%0A%0Aint+Bounce(int+x,+int+k)%0A%7B%0A++++int+mod+%3D+abs(x+%25+k)%3B%0A++++return+(x/k+%25+2)+%3F+k-mod+:+mod%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:44.94773519163764,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g63,filters:(b:%270%27,commentOnly:%270%27,directives:%270%27,intel:%270%27),options:%27-xc+-m64+-Os%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+6.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:55.05226480836237,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) for this. I mean, they should; it's a pretty simple function to optimize! I did [uncover a minor bug in GCC's x86-64 optimizer](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=81456), though, where it curiously produces *larger* code when you tell it to optimize for size and *smaller* code when you tell it to optimize for *speed*.

Comment: `m;f(x,k){m=abs(x%k);x=x/k%2?k-m:m;}` is shorter

Comment: Except that it doesn't actually return a value, @cows, other than under certain ill-defined circumstances due to a quirk of the GCC code generator on x86 targets. It's a template I see people use here, but it doesn't work for me, any more than pulling random garbage off the stack that just happens to be the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 37 Bytes

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##NYyxCoMwGIT3PsUfdEgGCyntkpqhQ4fOfQED@dEQk0gMYsF3T1X0loP77q5To8W@z8YNISb4/saE7vr2k4nBO/SJtphesR1ZpoRJF/RzLuwStC7nRpupsdJWM7ELr29y9eyU8RJ0uMAutU6hruB4OdIhGp9KGlFpKKHbbC8KAR@fsMXIipPSjRDCmRAny5k/Mr//AQ)

```hs
(!)=mod;x#k|odd$x`div`k=k-x!k|1<2=x!k
```

**How to use:**
Call as `15#14` for non-negative left arguments and as `(-13)#14` for negative left arguments, because Haskell would interpret `-13#14` as `-(13#14)` if you are using something like `ghci`. The TIO-link simply takes two command-line arguments.

**Explanation:**
First redefines the binary infix operator `!` to be the same as `mod`. Haskell's `mod` always outputs a non-negative value, so we don't need the `abs` that other solutions here do. It then checks whether `x/k` (integer division) is odd and if so, returns `k-x mod k` (ie the back-bounce) or else it returns `x mod k`.

Comment: This is probably just a matter of taste, but I personally prefer not defining `!` since it doesn't save any bytes over ``x#k|odd$x`div`k=k-x`mod`k|1<2=x`mod`k ``

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
d%ε¹ε
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJkJc61wrnOtSIsIiIsIjE0XG4xNSJd)

### How?

```
d%ε¹ε
d     # Double the (implicit) first input
 %    # Modulo the (implicit) second input by this
  ε   # Take the absolute difference of this and the (implicit) first input
   ¹ε # Take the absolute difference of this and the first input again
```

Answer (score 0):

## C (gcc), <s>43</s> 53 bytes

Edit: Fixed negative issue

```
int f(int x,int y){return x/y%2?abs(y-x%y):abs(x%y);}
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##fZDdboMwDIWvl6ewWiERFAoBqv5N3YvsJoS0jcTSKoQVVPXZWbzdbB3UF5Z9PstxjoyPUg5zbWTdVgpeG1fp8@K0J3@kWpdeG7RxcAgxdwxzT29WudYa6JI@yN5E2YR93AU93WKJxe4@JBGBlAEvIN7Dr0gJ5Axg9SDnxI/@H@eF15cjek5ino/pEPJsscFYgXISrue2rqBUIAwIKdXFibLGrrkqS/2WqVc33J@5fjiTI8hGQEqihBC050No8@2WsEfJQJ6EjSJsPumNvFysR4dwFuh3M2Pe15TxgtLdCPGXTaLlJEJbptmTlf6/6ymU/aD78AU)

Comment: This provides the wrong answer for (-13, 14) (-13 instead of 13). The modulus and remainder operations behave different on negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, 41 bytes

```
(lambda(x k)(- k(abs(-(mod x(* k 2))k))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7BCsIwEER/ZSiIs2LAtBH14r@kBqGkMcX2UC/99bopXVjesId5@@q7cVjZ5zzgnb/gjJ@g@@BIXmCdsMFNaN2W7XWDsc3O/fywuBfUCkHIoHYlP2FCtbhw1oV5QrEcKqgCVKdPbfAqjNqESN@ONEw5YOYJEbVIFJ21vFT4Bw)

Answer (score 0):

## R, 28 bytes

```
pryr::f(abs((x-k)%%(2*k)-k))
```

Which evaluates to the function:

```
function (k, x) 
abs((x - k)%%(2 * k) - k)
```

Which appears to be the method that most solutions use. I didn't look at them before making this.

Answer (score 0):

## MMIX, 20 bytes (5 instrs)

"xxd --jelly"

```
00000000: 1c02 0001 fe00 0006 24ff 0100 6600 02ff  ÷£¡¢“¡¡©$”¢¡f¡£”
00000010: f801 0000                                ẏ¢¡¡
```

disassembly and commentary

```
bounce  DIV  $2,$0,$1       // f:rR = x /% k
        GET  $0,rR          // rv = rR
        SUB  $255,$1,$0     // t = k - rv
        CSOD $0,$2,$255     // if(f odd) rv = t
        POP  1,0            // return rv
```

Not entirely sure what this does if k is negative, but it's probably the negative of bounce(x,k).

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 23 bytes

```hs
x#k=abs$mod(x-k)(2*k)-k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/v0I52zYxqVglNz9Fo0I3W1PDSCtbUzf7f25iZp5tbmKBb7xGQVFmXoleaV5yaVFRpYaypma0hoGOgqGJpo6ChrGOgjmINjSBiRiawli6hsYIJkLe0lBHwQLCMgKxYv8DAA)

Boring port of everything else <s>just to spite the existing answer for the pointless `(!)=mod;` ;)</s>.